# How to use custom annotations to document code in php

Tags: php, phpdoc

In my php code I have a lot of places, where I need to customize the default behaviour of the programming logic for different customers. For documentation purposes I want to annonate every custom logic. Perfect would be, if a tool can create a documentation like phpdocumentator from those annotations. The doctrine annotation library does not seem to fit, because I do not want to instantiate and parse classes automatically.

See this example of an annotation:

```
        /**
         * @Mytool(
         *     customer=Customer1,
         *     title=set sepa confirmed when calling sepa finalize to immediately confirm payments without bank import
         *     ticket=#2916
         * )
         */
        if ($this->context->isCustomer1()) {
            $mapper->setConfirmed($paymentIds);
        }
```

Can someone suggest a tool or keyword to search for?